# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1225589795" at path "_id" in TypeScript REST and Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I am trying to GET data based on deviceId but I am getting this error. The API has been designed in TypeScript using TypeScript REST.

[image: PostMan]
[image: Controller]
[image: Model]

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. Path `_id` has to be in a specific format and `1225589795` doesn't it.

You can check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTXnXkWS2XQ) how do you get the error but not [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V7X_TuR3S45).

Mongo `_id` has to be an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) which is compouned (as docs explain) by:

- a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
- a 5-byte random value
- a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

So the value you use has to match this and your number doesn't.